# Programmatically bind converter to column in DataGrid

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

I hope I can explain this clearly....
We are binding our `DataGrid` to a collection that comes from some datasource.
Attributes for each column are described in a different collection, so we create the columns at runtime and set properties on the column (readonly, for example) based on values in the attributes collection.

A new requirement is a 'required' attribute.  For columns that are required, I'd like to bind a converter that sets the DataGridCell's background color based on the value.  (The simplest case of converter would be some color if the cell were empty, and white if the user entered a value.  I'm sure more sophisticated validation will be expected in the future.)

I think it can be done in something like what I'm tinkering with now :

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content.Text}">
                    </TextBox>
                 </Border>
             </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
 </Style>
```

(Still need to add the converter somewhere....)
Or will what I want to do have to be done in code-behind?  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it. IDK if it's the best way, but it works and it's been a couple hours since you asked so....

Your DataGridCell is filled with the border/textbox so I'm assuming you want to change the textbox's background color since you won't see the DataGridCell's background.

Since you mentioned there could be more complex scenarios in the future, I used a multibinding with a converter and passed in the textboxes datacontext (by using <Binding />) and it's text value.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content.Text}">
                        <TextBox.Resources>
                            <local:ValidationBGConverter x:Key="ValidationBGConverter" />
                        </TextBox.Resources>
                        <TextBox.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                                <Setter Property="Background">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ValidationBGConverter}">
                                            <Binding />
                                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="Content.Text" />
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </TextBox.Style>
                    </TextBox>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And here is the converter:

```
public class ValidationBGConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.Length != 2)
            return Brushes.Black;
        var datacontext = values[0] as ViewData; // Or whatever the textbox's datacontext object is
        if (datacontext != null) // If null, probably the new item row
        {
            var txt = values[1] as string; // Textbox text
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt))
                return Brushes.Red;
            if (txt.Length < 3)
                return Brushes.Pink;
            if (txt.Length > 5)
                return new LinearGradientBrush(Colors.White, Colors.Blue, 90.0);
        }
        return Brushes.White;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And, a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Very helpful, thanks.  Particularly the part about passing the DataContext as a parameter:<Binding />.